# What are these two USB devices and how do I disable them?

Tags: drivers, usb

After running Powertop to do some tests with power usage, I realised that I have two USB devices listed that are not actually in use and that I would like to remove completely from my system.

```
USB device: usb-device-8087-0a2b
USB device: XiaoMi USB 2.0 Webcam (SunplusIT Inc)
```

When I installed Ubuntu I checked the option to automatically install drivers, so I'm going to suppose that's where these two came from.

Is there a way I can

- Understand what the first one is
- Figure out the drivers connected to both
- Remove those drivers so that they wouldn't get activated anymore

I don't have any other information about what they could be and nothing else is connected via USB to the laptop.

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.01 LTS

Edit: I checked in System Monitor and I can't find anything that could be related to them.

Edit 2: Running `for device in $(ls /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/product); do echo $device;cat $device;done`

Resulted in

```
/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-5/product
XiaoMi USB 2.0 Webcam
```

and `lsusb`

Resulted in:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f3:0c1a Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05c8:03a2 Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Which should be the first

Edit 3: `echo '1-5' | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind`

Resulted in

```
1-5
tee: /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind: No such device
```

Comment: output of `for device in $(ls /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/product); do echo $device;cat $device;done` ?

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lsusb` I suspect the first isting is bluetooth.

Comment: Added output of both commands with results, I'm still unsure what the bluetooth one actually is but how would I go about removing the Webcam in the meantime

Comment: Nevermind I copied the wrong one, the bluetooth one is something related to intel so it's probably best to keep it.

Comment: maybe try `echo '1-5' | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind`? to disable the webcam

Comment: What does `lsusb` say about the webcam? We need the usb.id.

Comment: Added the results of the command. lsusb doesn't say anything about the camera, I added all that it says in the OP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first item is this:

```
USB device: usb-device-8087-0a2b
```

A search for the usb.id 8087:0a2b suggests that is the bluetooth segment of the wireless/bluetooth card. Generally, in Settings, there is a slider to turn bluetooth off and on.

The second item is this:

```
05c8:03a2 Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink)
```

Searching for that wording finds this page: https://certification.ubuntu.com/catalog/make/Cheng%20Uei%20Precision%20Industry%20Co.%2C%20Ltd%20%28Foxlink%29/

This seems to confirm that the device is the webcam. Next, we find this: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/webcam-not-recognized-4175495176/ That page suggests that the driver is *uvcvideo*. Confirm that it is loaded:

```
lsmod | grep video
```

If it is, and you wish to disable the device altogether, blacklist the driver:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist uvcvideo"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
modprobe -r uvcvideo
exit
```

The driver has a long list of dependencies, one or more of which may load despite the blacklist. We may need to blacklist a few more after a trial and error.

**EDIT**: Reboot and see if there are any of these still loaded: uvcvideo,videodev,videobuf2-core,videobuf2-v4l2,videobuf2-vmalloc,media

If so, blacklist them one at a time and reboot and check again until none is left.

Comment: uvcvideo was loaded. I blacklisted it but the webcam is still there.

Comment: See my edit above in a few moments.

Comment: None were loaded, although I found video                  45056  1 i915 not sure if it's related

Comment: i915 is your video card driver; I doubt that it is related. Do not blacklist *video*. I think you are all set!

Comment: If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: https://askubuntu.com/tour

Comment: Sorry, wasn't at my pc. Thank you for the help!